# Asp.net MVC 2: Understanding CRUD, specfically actions Create ( there are 2)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone tell help me understand the new CRUD scaffolding that is included with MVC 2?

Let me explain, for example below you have 2 Create Actions...

Now i presume that if i have the form "Post to itself" then the second with Attribute POST is executed - IS THIS CORRECT? so a form within a view that when Submitted submits to itself??, but when would the standard Create be called i.e. the 1 that has the // GET comment at the start.

I do understand that the default action is Index hence this would be normally called when my page is displayed but i can't seem to find any info on Create action. I presume its a magic word hence it needs to be called Create ???

```
    // GET: /Customer/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Customer/Create

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Index is the only the default action because in most cases, that's how the routing is setup. You can create a route that that makes Create the default action.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help... Its clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Create()` (no attributes) is called when the page is first loaded. ie. The empty form is displayed to the user

`Create(FormCollection)` (`AcceptVerbs` attribute) is called when the form is submitted with data.

Both can use the same `ASPX` as a view.

Comment: Hi, but i thought Index is called when the page is first loaded, this is the default action for the controller? ...

Comment: In the default configuration, `Index` is called when there is no action specification in the url (ie. `/Customer`). The first `Create` method in your sample is called when `/Customer/Create` is called initially (ie. HTTP GET), and the second `Create` is called when the data is posted from the form (ie. HTTP POST)

Comment: Richard put it rather nicely. One thing to note - this is no different in version 2 then it was in first version.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magic about the name 'Create'. Any normal link to the create action (say, one created by a `Url.Action("Create")` call) would result in a page request to the non-POST (GET) version. A form on the GET version of the page with method="POST" will result in the POST version getting called. You can use this same pattern for actions with other names.